# Abstract Linear Algebra Inner Product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products

Let $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ be a vector such that $\|u\|=1$ (for the usual inner product). Prove that there exists an $n\times n$ orthogonal matrix whose first row is $u$.

Comment: See this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process

Comment: I've noticed that you have asked three questions during the last 3 hours. I wanted to make sure that you are aware of the quotas 50 questions/30 days and 6 questions/24 hours, so that you can plan posting your questions accordingly. (If you try to post more questions, StackExchange software will not allow you to do so.)
For more details see [meta](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/4770/).

Comment: Your question was put on hold, the message above (and possibly comments) should give an explanation why. You might try to edit your question to address these issues. Note that the next edit puts your post in the review queue, where users can vote to reopen this. (Therefore it would be good to avoid minor edits and improve your question as much as possible with the next edit.)

Answer (score 2):

If you have vector $\vec u=(a_1,a_2,\dots,a_n)$, then obviously the vectors
$$
\begin{align*}
\vec v_1=&(a_2,-a_1,0,\dots,0)\\
\vec v_2=&(0,a_3,-a_2,0,\dots,0)\\
&\vdots\\
\vec v_{n-1}=&(0,\dots,0,a_{n-1},-a_n)
\end{align*}
$$
are perpendicular to $\vec u$, i.e. $\langle \vec u, \vec v_i \rangle=0$.

Do you know how you can use these vectors to get an [orthogonal matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_matrix)? (Hint: What lengths do rows of an orthogonal matrix have?)

Notice that you still need do tweaking if one of the vectors $\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_{n-1}$ is zero, i.e., if the given vector $\vec u$ contains two consecutive zeroes somewhere.

---

It was pointed out in comments, that you could also use the fact that every set of orthonormal vectors can be extended to an orthonormal basis. This can be done using [Gram-Schmidt process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram%E2%80%93Schmidt_process).

However, for the case where you only have one vector, there is also a simple way without relying on the above result.

Comment: setting A=[v1,v2,...v,n] and AA^t = 1?

Comment: The vectors $\vec v_i$ do not have lenght equal to !, so you need to modify them a bit. Also, you should put these vectors in rows, since you want $\vec u$ to be the first row. Notice that you still will need do some minor changes if one of the vectors $\vec v_1,\dots,\vec v_{n-1}$ is zero, i.e., if the given vector $\vec u$ contains two consecutive zeroes.